# New tag for the health interoperability standard FHIR

Tags: discussion, tags

FHIR (http://hl7.org/fhir) is an important new standard from the health interoperability standards organisation HL7 ([hl7](/questions/tagged/hl7)). We'd like to use Stack Overflow as a forum to answer questions about this standard, and provide help to new users.

How can we create a tag for [fhir](/questions/tagged/fhir) to help coordinate this activity?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a support forum. (It's not a forum at all, actually.)

Comment: I'll note the distinction in the reference to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Ask a question that's related to the tag and [fits SO's format](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), or find an existing question that's lacking the tag. Post a link to it here and someone with enough reputation can go add the tag if it's considered relevant enough for the question. The tag is available for further questions for everyone from then on.

Comment: Existing questions:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598979/fhir-resource-that-supports-concept-no-known-allergy
 -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537493/use-of-include-in-fhir
 -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313704/wso2-aggregator-xpath-couldnt-traverse/16320227#16320227
 -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283942/wso2-custom-mediator-is-not-returning-in-proper-xml-format

thanks